# Install Multiple OS on USB Drive

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, operating-systems

I would like to install multiple OS on USB Drive with as less partitions as possible.

One way I thought of doing that is via Ventoy. I haven't tested this approach but it goes like this.

1. Install OS on USB.
2. Make an ISO of the Installed USB
3. Repeated for all OS.
4. Copy ISOs to Ventoy USB

But I think this would make a Static OS where you can't Installed any more Apps or User Data unless you outsource it to another Partition.

I think Installing OS on USB would also cause Directory Conflicts as USB may have a different letter on different PC (fixable by assigning a letter far down alphabet to USB)
and I have no idea how exactly shortcut and directories will play out in linux/MAC OS's.

So, what's the best way of going about it?

Comment: The best way is to just treat it as a "normal" drive. I don't know if installer of some distros would do silly stuff these days, but generally speaking there's nothing "special" in USB drive when it comes to Linux or AFAIK, BSDs. Only Windows is somewhat flawed in USB booting and "respect" the SCSI removable medium bit, and there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: What you might need to deal with specifically is that if you need it to be actually portable, there are stuff to concern, such as initramfs that include all the driver that might be needed, and bootloader installed in way that NVRAM registration is not involved when it comes to UEFI. Also support for booting on BIOS/CSM might be desired as well. The one thing about the drive itself might be the concern of flash wear (if it's a thumb drive instead of a bridged SATA / NVMe SSD), in which there are something that can be optimized (such as avoiding `atime` update or so)

Comment: For modern Windows, you will find the USB approach slower than frozen molasses.  Linux I have not tried.  A portable Laptop computer will work better.